# Can't predict the result. Get wrong result in Multi label classification with OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

Multi Label Classification

```
gender  age weight  height  vitamin_A   vitamin_C   vitamin_D
0       55  64      128     0           1           0
0       54  72      135     0           1           0
0       82  70      150     1           1           1
0       82  70      150     1           1           1
0       59  64      107     0           1           0
```

features are gender, age, weight, height

labels are vitamin A, C, D

```
X = df[['gender', 'age', 'weight', 'height']]
y = df[['vitamin_A', 'vitamin_C', 'vitamin_D']]
```

I did simple multi label classification model by OneVsRestClassifier.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)
LR_pipeline = Pipeline([('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='sag'), n_jobs=-1))])
labels = ['vitamin_A', 'vitamin_C', 'vitamin_D']
acc_classifier = []

for label in labels:
    LR_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train[label])
    prediction = LR_pipeline.predict(X_test)
    acc = accuracy_score(y_test[label], prediction)
    acc_classifier.append(acc)

df_ = pd.DataFrame({'Label': labels, 'Accuracy': acc_classifier})
df_

    Label      Accuracy
0   vitamin_A   0.75
1   vitamin_C   0.65
2   vitamin_D   1.00
```

**The original code is in [code link](https://github.com/hoggy999/multilabel/blob/main/multilabelclassifier.ipynb).
The data is in [data link](https://github.com/hoggy999/multilabel/blob/main/vitamin.csv).**

But I do not know how to use the model. I did it but it seem wrong result. Because every time I tried it get same only and 1,1,1 only.

```
data_test = [[0, 82, 70, 150]] 
for label in labels:
     y_predict = LR_pipeline.predict(data_test)
     print(y_predict)
```

result is `[1][1][1]` every time even change number.

**My expert is:**

Input: gender=0, age=55, weight=64, height=128

Result1: vitamin A is 0, vitamin C is 1, vitamin D is 0

Result2: vitamin A is 0.64, vitamin C is 0.82, vitamin D is 0.34

```
vitamin_A vitamin_B vitamin_C vitamin_A_prob vitamin_B_prob vitamin_C_prob
0         1         0         0.64           0.82           0.34
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you're fitting the same model multiple times. The `fit` method reinitializes the model, discarding any previously trained parameters.

Second, the provided dataset is not multi-label, because there is a "2" for a row of column "vitamin_A". Supposing this is just a typo, you can directly use `OneVsRestClassifier.fit` on the whole dataset, no need for fitting for each label. Just run:

```py
LR_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction = LR_pipeline.predict(X_test)
subset_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,prediction)
accuracy_per_label = [accuracy_score(y_test[l],prediction[:,i]) for i,l in enumerate(labels)]
```

`OneVsRestClassifier` does what your training loop is doing: training one binary classifier for each label separately as it if was a binary classification problem. `OneVsRestClassifier` is more commonly called Binary Relevance method.

Answer (score 0):

Turn pandas **output** data frame to numpy y_test.to_numpy() = (samples, n_classes) and do a direct fit; No need for looping each category. This works for me, test inputs are not the same

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier


df = pd.read_csv("vitamin.csv")

X = df[['gender', 'age', 'weight', 'height']]
y = df[['vitamin_A', 'vitamin_C', 'vitamin_D']]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression(solver='sag')).fit(X_test.to_numpy(), y_test.to_numpy())


data_test1 = [[0, 57, 79, 145]] #  
data_test2 = [[0, 59, 64, 107]] # 
data_test3= [[0, 89, 74, 107]] # 
y_predict1 = clf.predict(data_test1)
y_predict2 = clf.predict(data_test2)
y_predict3 = clf.predict(data_test3)
print(*y_predict1)
print(*y_predict2)
print(*y_predict3)
```

```
[1 1 0]
[0 0 0]
[0 0 0]
```